# JMETER 4. 0 | JMeter distributed load testing | jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group | Slave Machine | CPU Utilization

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-4.0, distributed-testing

1. When executing the script Slave 1 CPU Utilization = 40% and Slave 2 CPU Utilization = 4%. Only one slave machine is generating load i.e Slave 1 but Slave 2 is not generating load. How do I ensure both the machine generates load with respect the threads 50 running on each machine. While the report show that total 100 threads are completed.
2. How to know a slave is generating load.

Configuration:

```
Master(My own machine)
2 slaves machines
Thread: jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group
Users=50
Hold Load=300sec
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check `access log` of your web server to see from what ips it gets requests.

Could you specify what web server do you use?

For Apache it can be:

- `/var/log/apache/access.log`
- `/var/log/apache2/access.log`
- `/var/log/httpd/access.log`

In the log you should see something like that:

```
127.0.0.1 - test [1/Feb/2019:10:34:12 -0700] "GET /test-image.jpg HTTP/2" 200 1479
```

where `127.0.0.1` - ip of your load agents.

Comment: Webserver: Apache

Comment: Check some of that logs
/var/log/apache/access.log
/var/log/apache2/access.log
/var/log/httpd/access.log